# HTTPS and Firebase authentication

Tags: authentication, firebase

I was wondering, how can I authenticate requests to FireBase?

I have created new firebase account, marked **Enable Email & Password Authentication**, created a user with e-mail/password and using **{ ".read": "auth != null" }** in security rules for read access.

Using PostMan plugin for chrome, selected basic auth, entered e-mail/password, GET to https://crackling-fire-NNNN.firebaseio.com/key.json but I always get { "error": "Permission denied" }. It is working if I remove security rules.

HTTPS Basic Auth is not allowed in FireBase?

Can anyone provide some simples examples in pure HTTP how to authenticate GET/PUT/DELETE requests?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you question, you would like to use firebase purely with REST services, including authentication. For what I understand, if you want to do that you will need a server that generates a token that then you can append to the querystring. So if what you want is a serverless app that uses REST services, including logging in, the answer is you cannot. Correct me If I'm wrong

Answer (score 5):

I am posting this answer only to help other users to understand how FireBase works.

What I needed was to create an application that allows user (with password) to access his data stored on some server using REST. I thought that I could use FireBase to do that.

But. I have investigated a little bit and find out that FireBase uses JSON Web Tokens (JWT) to authenticate users. Token generation should be done on (other) server side, because it uses FireBase secret. So, apparently you can't send username&password to FireBase. FireBase SDK to be used by another server, and not client. Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: For those who may be interested, there is a draft for JSON Web Token (JWT) at OAuth group: [link](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-json-web-token-29)

Answer (score 3):

Firebase authentication when using the REST API requires an `auth` token to be passed.

See:

- https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/api/#section-query-parameters
- https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/guide/user-auth.html#section-rest-server-authentication
- https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/guide/user-auth.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Can you tell me how can I generate token without using Firebase SDK?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "Firebase SDK", but there are helper libraries to generate tokens over on: https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/guide/user-auth.html#section-rest-token-helper-libraries. They're all on github, so you can simply check in the code what they're doing.